# MobileVLCKit taking to much space in the project

Tags: swift, cocoapods, vlc

I want to play webM files in my iOS project. I have installed pod 'MobileVLCKit' and it is working perfectly fine. But only the framework is the size of 1.58GB. This is too much to have in any project. Any other option available to play webM files or is there any way to reduce this framework size?